# jasmine httpbackend any url to return mock data

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, coffeescript

I am building a test for my Angular app using Jasmine.

I want to mock the api call to return some data but my api call on my controller is

```
$scope.getSubjects = ->
  $http.get "/api/students/#{$scope.freshBooking.StudentId}"
  .then (response) ->
    $scope.subjects = response.data.Subjects
```

On my test I have

```
@httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/api\/students/.*/).respond ->
  [200, {data: 'subjects'}]

it 'should have data in subjects', ->
  expect(@scope.subjects).toBeUndefined()
  @scope.getSubjects()
  @httpBackend.flush()
  expect(@scope.subjects).toBeDefined()
```

I get an error saying "Expected undefined to be defined." so I'm guessing I'm not returning any data for the api call.

How would I go about getting this to work? Is my regex incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression seems to be incorrect. Try following

```
^\/api\/students\/.*
```

Slash added after "students" to escape forward slash, removed the slash at the end to regex as the actual API call is not having slash at the end.

Further regex group can be used to extract the Student ID

```
\/api\/students\/#(.*)  //The brackets group would extract Student ID
```